# Can't login to my website with facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have website with facebook login. 
When it was on previous server it was working perfectly but now when i transfer it to "godaddy vps" it won't work.

I add the new domain to the app domain in the app also i've added the new callback url to "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs".

I'm getting this error:

```
Graph returned an error: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
```

Any idea how can i solve this

Comment: It is possible that the change was not handled by their cron job yet.

Comment: i was trying to change it from a week ago with no luck

Comment: Then the scenario I described is not the case. If I were you I would try to find out which URL value was not liked by the code. It might be surprising.

Comment: How can i find this URL ??

Comment: Somewhere the error is being thrown in the code. At that point the URL should be available in a variable, a parameter or something like that. You need to look for a conditional where the validation fails.